# Susy: first and last keywords not being applied

Tags: susy-sass

It doesn't matter how I apply first or last keywords they do do not seem to be being applied.

I have:
$susy: (columns: 12, column-width: 60px, gutter-width: 20px, grid-padding: $grid-padding, container-style: static, gutter-position: split);

I have tried :

```
.more {
   @include span(first 3 of 6);
}


.more {
   @include span(3);
   @include first;
}
```

The result is always:

```
width: 46.66667%;
float: left;
margin-left: 1.66667%;
margin-right: 1.66667%;
```

I would expect the the left margin to have been taken off? What am I missing please?

Answer (score 1):

`split` gutters are based on a model similar to 960gs and others - where the gutters aren't removed at the edges. That makes it so you don't ever *need* `first` or `last` arguments. Otherwise, I'm not sure I see the advantage of using split gutters.